# rearrange multidimensional array on basis of value of inner array and duplicated values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have an array like this:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [route_id] => 1539871200
        [booking_id] => 171
        [route] => Boattrip Destination 2
        [date] => 18 October 2018 
        [time] => 14:00 - 16:00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [route_id] => 1539856800
        [booking_id] => 170
        [route] => Boattrip Destination 2
        [date] => 18 October 2018 
        [time] => 10:00 - 12:00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [route_id] => 1539856800
        [booking_id] => 162
        [route] => Boattrip Destination 2
        [date] => 18 October 2018 
        [time] => 10:00 - 12:00
    )
)
```

Route_id's always share the same `date`, `time` and `route` values. Only thing that is different are the booking id's.

Now what I want the arrays to be sorted by `route_id` and then a create a new array having below structure

```
Array (

[1539871200] => Array
    (
    [route] => Boattrip Destination 2
    [date] => 18 October 2018 
    [time] => 14:00 - 16:00
    [booking_ids] => Array
        (                  
           [0] => 171               
        )
    )

[1539856800] => Array
    (
    [route] => Boattrip Destination 2
    [date] => 18 October 2018 
    [time] => 10:00 - 12:00
    [booking_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 170
            [1] => 162    
        )
    )
)
```

This was my attempt:

```
$output = array();
foreach($bookings as $item) {
    if(!isset($output[$item['route_id']])) {
        $output[$item['route_id']] = array();
    }
    $catName = $item['route_id'];
    unset($item['route_id']);
    $output[$catName][] = $item;
}
```

But that only groups the `route_id`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$routes = [];
foreach ($yourArray as $booking)
{
    $bookingId = $booking['booking_id'];
    $routeId = $booking['route_id'];

    // Initialise an empty array set
    if (!array_key_exists($routeId, $routes)) {
        // Create a new array for booking IDs
        $booking['booking_ids'] = [];
        // Remove the IDs you don't want
        unset($booking['booking_id'], $booking['route_id']);

        // Push your booking data
        $routes[$routeId] = $booking;
    }

    // Push the current booking ID into an existing set
    $routes[$routeId]['booking_ids'][] = $bookingId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have delivered your exact desired output using best practices.   No unnecessary variables are generated. No `unset()` calls.  The only function in the snippet is `ksort()` and I'm not even sure you want it.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rjinc))

```
foreach ($array as $set) {
    if (isset($result[$set["route_id"]])) {
        $result[$set["route_id"]]["booking_ids"][] = $set["booking_id"];  // push new element
    } else {
        $result[$set["route_id"]] = [
            "route" => $set["route_id"],            // new key name, transfer value
            "date" => $set["date"],                 // transfer key and value
            "time" => $set["time"],                 // transfer key and value
            "booking_ids" => [$set["booking_id"]]   // new key name, write value as first element
        ];
    }
}
ksort($result);  // ... you did say you wanted to sort them by route_id
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1539856800 => 
  array (
    'route' => 1539856800,
    'date' => '18 October 2018',
    'time' => '10:00 - 12:00',
    'booking_ids' => 
    array (
      0 => 170,
      1 => 162,
    ),
  ),
  1539871200 => 
  array (
    'route' => 1539871200,
    'date' => '18 October 2018',
    'time' => '14:00 - 16:00',
    'booking_ids' => 
    array (
      0 => 171,
    ),
  ),
)
```